# Disabling the port numbering automatically in simulink

Tags: matlab, port, simulink

i am trying to give numbers to ports according to a wrapper i built in simulink. but when i give a number and move on to next and port and give it another number then the previous port number sometimes gets changed/adjusted automatically in simulink. Is there a way to disable this property in simulink ?

Comment: Can you show some example? Because I don't understand - is it port for hardware or for bus signal or smth else?

Comment: it's just inports. for example if i have 10 inports and i delete the 8th one. then 9th inport gets changed to 8th and 10th gets changed to 9th. i wanted to know if it was possible to disable this setting. but anyway i figured out another way for this to work. @Mikhail_Sam